# How to subscribe Ionic 2 platform.pause EventEmitter?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to use the following code to subscribe, but it doesn't work.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/test.html',
})

export class Test {

  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('paused')
    });
  }
}
```

I'm using Ionic 2 with TypeScript, Angular 2. As `platform.pause` is an EventEmitter provided by Ionic 2, I suppose it should be able to be subscribed. However, when I put the application to the background, `console.log('pause')` is not fired.

Should I add `Platform` to providers or something like that? Plus, this.platform is not `null`. `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{console.log('ready')})` works perfectly.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? I `paused` not printed?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  
Yes, exactly. It hasn't been printed as it suppose to

Comment: what is `this.platform.pause` here ? update your question with some more code or you can reproduce your problem on plunker

Comment: Try using `document.addEventListener('pause', () => { });` copied from this blog / tutorial https://webcake.co/listening-for-pause-and-resume-events-in-ionic-2/

Comment: @Will.Harris Yes, I know. But my boss prefer using native Ionic 2. And here(https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-hardware-back-button/41384/3) the Ionic Team said that the `back button` hasn't been implemented. So does it imply that the `this.platform.pause` hasn't been implemented too?

Comment: Well if you implement my method and test it on a device you will at least know if the pause event is fired or not. I don't know of any other way to bind to the pause event because there don't seem to be any examples of binding to an Event Emitter in the controller, so try asking this on the Ionic forum :)

Comment: @Will.Harris Well, it works. And finally my boss agree not to use that kind of implementation.

Answer (score 11):

I think you missed platform.ready() as below

```
constructor( private platform: Platform ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {    
        this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('[INFO] App paused');
        });

        this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('[INFO] App resumed');
        });
    });
}
```

The above code worked for me. Hope it helps you as well.